# multer: upload files with dynamic folder name and file name from function arguments

Tags: typescript, express, multer

I am pretty new to Node JS and TS and I want to name my files based on function arguments.

**upload.ts**

```
import multer from 'multer';
import multerS3 from 'multer-s3';

import s3 from '../config/s3';

const upload = (foldername: string, filename: string) => {
    return multer({
        storage: multerS3({
            s3: s3,
            bucket: '',
            key: function (req: any, file: any, cb: any) {
                const fullPath = foldername + '/' + filename;
                cb(null, fullPath);
            }
        })
    });
}

export default upload;
```

**file.ts**

```
import { Router } from 'express';
import fileController from '../controllers/file';
import upload from '../middlewares/upload';

const router = Router();

router.post('/upload', upload.array("files"), fileController.upload);
router.get('/', fileController.getFileNames);
router.get('/:foldername/:filename', fileController.download);
 
export default router;
```

However, the error I get is that `Property 'array' does not exist on type '(foldername: string, filename: string) => Multer'.ts(2339)` From reading the docs, I think it is because the .array() only works on type Multer, but I am unsure how to fix this.

I have already searched a lot for naming dynamically, but I have only come across answers that accept the folder name and file name from the req.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: As `upload` is a function that returns a function, you'll have to call it like: `upload('foldername', 'filename').array('files')`

Comment: @kausko Thank you so much! I can't believe I missed that.